# Feed the Beast Mod-pack Cannot connect to servers or create new worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-feed-the-beast

When I log into FTB, using any of the new mod-packs, e.g. FTB Monster or Agrarian Skies, the game works fine until I try to create new world or log into a server.

If I try to create a new world FTB stops responding, I have left it alone for up to an hour afterwards for no effect. When I try to connect to a server I can see the server list, but if i try to connect it remains at 'Logging On'.

I have uploaded the [console log](http://pastebin.com/vNKhWQZq) and the [error report](http://pastebin.com/n4J7EJhN) to PasteBin.

The error message in the console is

```
2014-06-13 21:08:52 [SEVERE] [Minecraft-Server] Encountered an unexpected exception NoClassDefFoundError 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider 
at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71197_b(IntegratedServer.java:105) 
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:445) 
at net.minecraft.server.ThreadMinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:583) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:113) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
... 3 more
```

I have updated java and re-installed FTB several times.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. This is a good first question. I have submitted an edit to improve readability. I also took the liberty to paste the important part (the error) from the console log to the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man, really appreciated and that edit is much improved. :)

Comment: It is important to note that Agrarian Skies, being a skyblock, has a map generator that produces only void. "Start a new world" will always drop you into the void. Any new multiplayer maps into which you didn't import a "world" from an external source will also have this problem. Once you connect to either world you will die. Once you die you will be locked out because Agrarian Skies is by default on hardcore mode (HQM, not technically hardcore - but the effect is the same, lockout). Your connection issues may not be connection issues. They could easily be misunderstandings of the mod pack.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's modded Minecraft Tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a missing `.jar` problem, 
try putting this on your `libs` folder: http://files.minecraftforge.net/fmllibs/bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar

If that doesn't work, try deleting your libs folder and install FTB again.
Hope it helped.

Comment: Actually not FTB, but modpack